# Using more than one condition in linq's where method

Tags: c#

I have a line of code using where:

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5);
```

How can I insert more than one condition? So I can say `x => predicate && y => predicate`?

Thanks

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can roll your separate conditions into a single predicate if you like:

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => (x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5) && (x.Foo == "test"));
```

Or you can use a separate `Where` call for each condition:

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5)
                .Where(x => x.Foo == "test");
```

Comment: Considering big clauses with much information, do both cases have the same complexity or is the first one slower?

Comment: @alaxid: I would expect the second one to be *slightly* slower, because each `Where` call incurs a small extra overhead (method call, delegate invocation etc). I wouldn't be worried about this in any normal day-to-day scenarios though.

Comment: What about OR clause? Multiplying .Where would act as AND

Answer (score 8):

no you can't define 2 delegates in the same where but you can build after each other or put both on same condition like this

```
 var result = codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5 && x.Body.Scopes.name == "" );

or 

 var result = codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5 )
        .where( y=> y.Body.Scopes.name == '' );

or 

 var result = codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5  )
.Union( codebase.Methods.Where(y => y.Body.Scopes.name == ''  ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example, where does `y` come from? The `Where` method takes a lambda with a single input parameter, which represents a single instance of the sequence you're operating against.

You can, of course, have multiple conditions against `x`:

```
Where(x => x.Foo > 5 && x.Bar < 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

What would "y" represent?

You can just use a standard && condition.  No need for a "y":

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5 && x.Body.SomethingElse < 14);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get it. What can you not do?

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Head.IsHairy && x.Body != null && x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5);
```

Comment: The y that is mystifying you is just sort of a stand-in for the <YourType> object to be tested against in the filter. It may be called an "Anonymous Delegate" but I am not sure. In any case, it just provides a variable for you to use to access the properties of your type in the lambda expression. You could use any legal variable name.

Answer (score 0):

like this..

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5 && x.Body.Scopes.Count < 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
codebase.Methods.Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Count > 5).Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.TypeName == "Scopes").Where(x => x.Body.Scopes.Level == LEVEL_HIGH);
```