# Multiple conditions in linq lambda query

Tags: linq-to-sql

### Three conditions in linq where clause using lambda expressions

```
List<Tbl_MVPConsultant> _objConsultants = _datalayer.Get_MVP_Consultants();

 _objConsultants = _objConsultants.Where(p => p.Country.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower()) ||
                    p.State.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower()) ||
                    p.City.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower())).ToList();
```

I'm trying to achieve a filter operation three times using the above query .. but i'm getting an error stating `object reference not set to an instance of an object` ..

Looking for a quick solution.Appreciate early efforts.
Thank you

Comment: are you sure _objConsultants has data? check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281083/using-more-than-one-condition-in-linqs-where-method

Comment: Yeah _objConsultants has data and the
 `_objConsultants = _objConsultants.Where(p => p.Country.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower()) ||
                    p.State.ToLower().Contains(SearchTextbox.ToLower())).ToList();`
I was able to fetch the results based on the two conditions but fails for the three condition statement.. @Niranjan Kala

Comment: @user3759894: Have you tried jon's suggested solution??

Comment: Yes you and Jon were both right about it.
There are some null values in the table.
How to apply the checking of nulls at the start of lambda, @Niranjan Kala ?
I'm very new to Linq ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to call `p.Country.ToLower` if `p.Country` is `null`.  Put `p.Country != null && p.State != null && p.City != null &&` at the start of the lambda.

Comment: You're right about it, there are some null values 
How to apply the checking of nulls at the start of lambda.
can you re write my query @jon